# How to get all manytomany objects in a queryset of objects

Tags: django

I have a model `Department` which has `Role`s which `User`s are linked to. I know the user, but need to get the `user.role.department_set.all()` (all departments the user's role belong to) and then get all the `role`s in each of those departments.

Models:

```
class User(AbtractUser):
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role)

class Role(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    roles = models.ManyToManyField()
```

How can I get all the departments which contains the user's role, then get the roles of all those departments?

I am doing something like this currently but it is a very expensive lookup:

```
    def get_departments(self):
        """Returns a list of departments the user is in."""
        return self.role.department_set.all()

    def get_users_departments_roles(self):
        """Returns all the roles of all the departments the user is in."""
        departments = self.get_departments()
        roles = Role.objects.none()
        for department in departments.iterator():
            for role in department.roles.all():
                roles |= Role.objects.filter(name=role.name)
        return roles
```

Side question: After typing all this out, would it be better to just add the a `department` field to each user? My concern is that if a role changes, I will also have to change the department at the same time and it will add complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter a Role queryset and follow the ManyToManyField relationship backwards using the name `department`

You can pass a queryset to the `__in` filter to produce a nested query

```
    def get_users_departments_roles(self):
        """Returns all the roles of all the departments the user is in."""
        departments = self.get_departments()
        return Role.objects.filter(department__in=departments).distinct()
```

Note however that certain databases (MySQL) don't perform nested queries very well, see [this warning](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#in) at the end of this section in the docs

Comment: I am confused. There is no `departments` field in `Role` so how does this work?

Comment: @DavidAlford relationships can be queried "backwards" using the `related_name` for the field or a default name that is generated.  For a ManyToManyField with no `related_name` you can query using the name of the model on the other end all lowercase

Comment: Wow. learned something new today which really helps. Given the warning would it be better to do: `departments = self.get_departments().values_list('pk', flat=True)`?

Comment: @DavidAlford If you are using MySQL then probably, although might be worth just testing each version out.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Missed that. I am using Postgres. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidAlford Something like `Role.objects.filter(department__roles=self.role)` may work without using a nested query although may perform fairly badly due to all the joins and is a little confusing as it follows the m2m relationship backwards and then forwards again

Comment: I will take a further look into the cost of db lookups and how to measure them as soon I have some extra time. thank you!